# Expand 1d tensor to 2d tensor along with the diagonal of the 2d tensor in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Is there any way, in Pytorch, to convert a 1d `tensor([[1., 2., 3., 4.]])` into

```
tensor([[1., 2., 3., 4.], 
        [2., 1., 2., 3.], 
        [3., 2., 1., 2.], 
        [4., 3., 2., 1.]])
```

Comment: it looks like you are looking to compute the distance from the diagonal, rather than expanding. What exactly are you after?

Answer (score 0):

`torch.roll` unfortunately only applies dimension-wise, so you will have to `expand` and use something like `torch.gather`, along with a set of index shifts:

```py
t = tensor([[1., 2., 3., 4.]])

idx = torch.arange(4)
idx = torch.stack([torch.roll(idx, shift) for shift in range(0,-4,-1)])

torch.gather(t.expand(4,-1), 1, idx)
```